# Conditionally set active class on menu using react router current route

Tags: reactjs, react-routing

I am using react router 1.0.2 and my routes look like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <IndexRoute component={Home}/>
        <Route path="triangles" component={Triangles}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector('.container')
);
```

My App component looks like this and I thought I could pass the location in the props:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Menu from './menu';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu/>
        <div className="jumbotron">
         {this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
            location: this.props.location
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

I want to conditionally set an active class on the Menu component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import { pushPath } from 'redux-simple-router';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

    export default class Menu extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
            <nav role="navigation" className="navbar navbar-default">
              <div id="navbarCollapse" className="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
                  <li className={this.props.location.pathname === '/' ? 'active' : ''}>
                    <Link to="/">Home</Link>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </nav>
        );
      }
    };
```

But the `this.props.location` is null when the menu's render function is called?

How can I pass props to child components?

Comment: I remember using props.params for this. I m not entirely sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're passing the prop into the correct element. The `children` of `App` would be whatever child route is being rendered (so either `Home` or `Triangles`), but you want the prop to be passed to `Menu`.

To do that, just pass it in via JSX:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import Menu from './menu';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Menu location={this.props.location} />
        <div className="jumbotron">
          {this.props.children}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 11):

To set class on the active navigation element

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

&

```
<NavLink to="/Home" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll want to use React Router's `<NavLink>` component that allow you to define styles or add a class when the link is active. Just set the `activeClassName` or `activeStyle` attribute to your `<NavLink>` component.

This is built into React Router, see the official docs for more details: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Comment: I believe the React component you need to use is <NavLink>. This is the one with extended functionality. This should be the right answer for 2017 and after.

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked has is using `NavLink` as it has this active class property.

1. First import it

   ```
   import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
   ```
2. Use an `activeClassName` to get the active class property.

   ```
   <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">
        Home
   </NavLink>

   <NavLink to="/store" activeClassName="active">
        Store
   </NavLink>

   <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">
        About Us
   </NavLink>
   ```
3. Style your class in the css by the property `active`.

   ```
   .active{
       color:#fcfcfc;
    }
   ```