# How do I add an active class to a Link from React Router?

Tags: react-router

I've created a bootstrap-style sidebar using `Link`. Here is a snippet of my code:

```html
<ul className="sidebar-menu">
  <li className="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
  <li><Link to="dashboard"><i className="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span></Link></li>
  <li><Link to="email_lists"><i className="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> <span>Email Lists</span></Link></li>
  <li><Link to="billing"><i className="fa fa-credit-card"></i> <span>Buy Verifications</span></Link></li>
</ul>
```

I want to set the class for the active path to `active` on the wrapping element `<li>`. I see there are other solutions out there that show how to do this like [Conditionally set active class on menu using react router current route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34410051/conditionally-set-active-class-on-menu-using-react-router-current-route), however I don't think that it's the best way to set an active class on a wrapper to a `Link`.

I also found https://github.com/insin/react-router-active-component but it feels like it is unnecessary.

In React Router, is this possible or do I need to use an external solution?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

On the Link component you can now add **activeClassName** or set **activeStyle**.

These allow you to easily add styles to the currently active link.

---

Previously, you could create a custom component that works like a wrapper to Link with the following logic.

In a file called nav_link.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class NavLink extends React.Component {
    render() {
        var isActive = this.context.router.route.location.pathname === this.props.to;
        var className = isActive ? 'active' : '';

        return(
            <Link className={className} {...this.props}>
                {this.props.children}
            </Link>
        );
    }
}

NavLink.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};

export default NavLink;
```

And use it as given below in your component:

```js
// ...
import NavLink from "./nav_link";
// ...

<nav>
    <ul className="nav nav-pills pull-right">
        <NavLink to="/">
            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> <span>Home</span>
        </NavLink>
        <NavLink to="about">
            <i className="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> <span>About</span>
        </NavLink>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: contentTypes in NavLink component should be static property not an instance property. Please correct.

Comment: Why not use `activeStyle` or `activeClassName` exposed by `react-router`. There is some [documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links) around it.

Comment: It appears that this no longer works as of react-router v4.0.0, as `router.isActive` no longer exists.  See: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-router-bootstrap/issues/186

Comment: With react-router 3.0.0 , got `TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined`

Comment: Yes it should be the accepted answer. It worked beautifully for me! However, there is more to the config than just these steps. For me, it just made sure that my <Link /> components in my nav were wrapped with this. There were other steps that made this work in the grand scheme of things. I will share them here a bit later when I have a moment.

Comment: When I tested this with Jest, it failed. It returned an error and/or undefined. So I looked into things further and played around more with code. I finally came up with a solution and it passed! I will be writing a post about it over the weekend and will share my results here. it was tricky and I had to do a good deal of research, refactoring and testing before I got there! So I'm sorry that I had to subsequently downvote this. Technically it worked, but it failed my test.

Comment: I used this code but when I navigate on my menu links, the class is not changing until I reload the page. What should I do to make it rerendered again every time I click on a Link?

Answer (score 86):

**React-Router V4** comes with a [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) component out of the box

To use, simply set the `activeClassName` attribute to the class you have appropriately styled, or directly set `activeStyle` to the styles you want. See [the docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md) for more details.

```html
<NavLink
  to="/hello"
  activeClassName="active"
>Hello</NavLink>
```

Comment: This is on the _wrapper_ to the link.

Comment: This outputs an anchor tag. The OP wants something that will output a list item.

Comment: Is this really working? I tried same but it's not working for me.

Answer (score 19):

For me what worked has is using NavLink as it has this active class property.

1. First import it

   ```
   import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
   ```
2. Use an activeClassName to get the active class property.

   ```
   <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">
    Home
   </NavLink>

   <NavLink to="/store" activeClassName="active">
    Store
   </NavLink>

   <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">
    About Us
   </NavLink>
   ```
3. Style your class in the css by the property active.

   ```
   .active{
     color:#fcfcfc;
    }
   ```

Comment: this works, thanks, found a solution to turn off the Home always being active also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51214763/navlink-from-react-router-dom-home-always-active/51214772

Answer (score 14):

This is my way, using location from props.
I don't know but history.isActive got undefined for me

```js
export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
render(){
const { location } = this.props;

const homeClass = location.pathname === "/" ? "active" : "";
const aboutClass = location.pathname.match(/^\/about/) ? "active" : "";
const contactClass = location.pathname.match(/^\/contact/) ? "active" : "";


return (
<div>
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li className={homeClass}><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li className={aboutClass}><Link to="about" activeClassName="active">About</Link></li>
        <li className={contactClass}><Link to="contact" activeClassName="active">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>

</div>
    );}}
```

Comment: `<li class={homeClass}> ... </li>`

change class => className

Answer (score 13):

Answer updated with ES6:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

class NavLink extends Component {
    render() {
        let isActive = this.context.router.isActive(this.props.to, true);
        let className = isActive ? "active" : "";

        return (
            <li className={className}>
                <Link {...this.props}/>
            </li>
        );
    }
}

NavLink.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
};

export default NavLink;
```

Then use it as described above.

Comment: `this.context.route` was undefined me for (newer version?), you can make work using `withRouter` function which passes router in params

Answer (score 10):

Just use `NavLink` rather than `Link`. It will add `.active` class automatically.

```
<Nav className="mr-auto">
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/home">Home</Nav.Link>
    <Nav.Link as={NavLink} to="/users">Users</Nav.Link>
</Nav>
```

Answer (score 8):

I didn't like the idea of creating a custom component, because if you have a different wrapping element you would have to create another custom component etc. Also, it is just overkill. So I just did it with css and activeClassName:

```html
<li className="link-wrapper">  <!-- add a class to the wrapper -->
  <Link to="something" activeClassName="active">Something</Link>
</li>
```

And then just add some css:

```css
li.link-wrapper > a.active {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Technically this doesn't style the li, but it makes the anchor fill the li and styles it.

Answer (score 5):

With `react-router-dom@4.3.1` (though any `4.x.x` should do I guess), we can use the `withRouter` HOC to accomplish this. For example, I want to implement the Bootstrap navbar and since it requires a class of `active` on `<li class="nav-item">` and not on the anchor tag, I made a new component called `NavItem` to encapsulate a single `li.nav-item`. The implementation is as follows:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const NavItem = ({ isActive, to, label }) => {
  let classes = ["nav-item"];
  if (isActive) classes.push("active");

  return (
    <li className={classes.join(" ")}>
      <Link className="nav-link" to={to}>
        {label}
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
};

export default withRouter(({ location, ...props }) => {
  const isActive = location.pathname === props.to;

  console.log(location.pathname, props.to);

  return <NavItem {...props} isActive={isActive} />;
});
```

As you can see, `NavItem` is just a stateless functional component which expects an `isActive` prop to determine whether `active` class should be added. Now, to update this prop as the location changes, we can make use of the `withRouter` HOC. You can pass any component to this function and it'll give it `{ match, location, history }` objects in its props along with the ones you pass down. Here, I am creating a functional component inline which receives these objects and determines whether the current link is the active one using the `location.pathname` property. This'll give us a `Boolean` and we can return the `NavItem` along with `isActive` set to the value we computed using `location.pathname`.

A working example of this can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/j3rmq0ll3w). Please let me know if there's an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

As of react-router-dom@4.3.1, we can just easily use the NavLink with activeClassName instead of Link. Example:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><NavLink to='/1' activeClassName="active">1</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to='/2' activeClassName="active">2</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to='/3' activeClassName="active">3</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Then in your CSS file:

```
.navbar li>.active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

The NavLink will add your custom styling attributes to the rendered element based on the current URL.

Document is [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeClassName-string)

Answer (score 5):

To set class on the active navigation element

`import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';`

&

`<NavLink to="/Home" activeClassName="active">Home</NavLink>`

Answer (score 5):

Current **React Router Version 5.2.0**

**activeStyle** is a **default css property** of NavLink component which is  imported from **react-router-dom**

So that we can write our own custom css to make it active.In this example i made background transparent and text to be bold.And I store it on a constant named **isActive**

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { NavLink} from "react-router-dom";

    function nav() {

          const isActive = {
            fontWeight: "bold",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)",
          };
    
    return (
          <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li className="nav-item">
              <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/Shop" activeStyle={isActive}>
                Shop
              </NavLink>
            </li>
          </ul>
          );

    export default nav;
```

Comment: Throws error: `Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <NavLink> outside a <Router>`

Answer (score 5):

In react router Version 6, we're doing it by NavLink and setting its className property.

We're specifying a function which will be called on every route change here.

```js
   import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
   
   import classes from './MainHeader.module.css';
   
   const MainHeader = () => {
     return (
       <header className={classes.header}>
         <nav>
           <ul>
             <li>
               <NavLink className={({isActive}) => isActive ? classes.active : ''} to='/welcome'>
                 Welcome
               </NavLink>
             </li>
             <li>
               <NavLink className={({isActive}) => isActive ? classes.active : ''} to='/products'>
                 Products
               </NavLink>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </nav>
       </header>
     );
   };
   
   export default MainHeader;
```

[also, you can find a whole tutorial on it on this link](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-classes-with-react-router)

Comment: Thanks, this works! 
Maybe you should consider add  ```js to you  codesample for colorize

Comment: Thanks for the colorization suggestion. It also worked :) Generally, stackoverflow colorizes on its own. It seems that for the jsx we need to add some hints for it :)

Answer (score 4):

You can actually replicate what is inside [NavLink](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js#L24) something like this

```js
const NavLink = ( {
  to,
  exact,
  children
} ) => {

  const navLink = ({match}) => {

    return (
      <li class={{active: match}}>
        <Link to={to}>
          {children}
        </Link>
      </li>
    )

  }

  return (
    <Route
      path={typeof to === 'object' ? to.pathname : to}
      exact={exact}
      strict={false}
      children={navLink}
    />
  )
}
```

just look into [NavLink](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js#L24) source code and remove parts you don't need ;)

Answer (score 4):

```js
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter, Link} from "react-router-dom";

const SidenavItems = (props) => {
                                     // create simple list of links
    const items = [
        {
            type: "navItem",
            icon: "home",
            text: "Home",
            link: "/",
            restricted: false
        },
        {
            type: "navItem",
            icon: "user-circle",
            text: "My Profile",
            link: "/user",
            restricted: false
        },
        {
            type: "navItem",
            icon: "sign-in",
            text: "Login",
            link: "/login",
            restricted: false
        },
    ];

    const element = (item, i) => {  // create elements (Links)
                        // check if this is a current link on browser
        let active = "";

        if (props.location.pathname === item.link) {
            active = "active";
        }

        return (
            <div key={i} className={item.type}>
                <Link
                    to={item.link}
                    className={active} // className will be set to "active" 
                >                      // or ""
                    {item.text}
                </Link>
            </div>
        )
    };

    const showItems = () => {     // print elements
        return items.map((item, i) => {
            return element(item, i)
        })
    };

    return (
        <div>
            {showItems()}  // print all the links we created in list
        </div>
    )
};
export default withRouter(SidenavItems);
```

Comment: Hello! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Hi! I have added some comments

Answer (score 4):

**React Router v6:**

Source: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-classes-with-react-router)

You'll want to use the `className` property which now accepts a function and passes an `isActive` boolean property:

```js
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) => (isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive')}
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

This is great for adding multiple classes too, and was a breaking change in v6 beta:

```js
<NavLink
  to="users"
  className={({ isActive }) =>
    isActive ? 'bg-green-500 font-bold' : 'bg-red-500 font-thin'
  }
>
  Users
</NavLink>
```

Read more and live demo: [Active NavLink Classes with React Router](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/active-navlink-classes-with-react-router)

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @BaiJiFeiLong's answer, add an `active={}` property to the link:

```
<Nav.Link as={Link} to="/user" active={pathname.startsWith('/user')}>User</Nav.Link>
```

This will show the `User` link as active when any path starts with '/user'.  For this to update with each path change, include `withRouter()` on the component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar'
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav'

function Header(props) {
    const pathname = props.location.pathname

    return (
        <Navbar variant="dark" expand="sm" bg="black">
            <Navbar.Brand as={Link} to="/">
                Brand name
            </Navbar.Brand>
            <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/user" active={pathname.startsWith('/user')}>User</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link as={Link} to="/about" active={pathname.startsWith('/about')}>About</Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    )
}

export default withRouter(Header)   // updates on every new page
```

Answer (score 2):

## One of the way you can use it

When you are using the Functional component then follow the instruction here.

- add a variable in your component
- create an event change browser URL change/or other change
- re-assign the current path (URL)
- use javascript match function and set active or others

Use the above code here.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavItems = () => {
    let pathname = window.location.pathname;
    useEffect(() => {
        pathname = window.location.pathname;
    }, [window.location.pathname]);

    return (
        <>
            <li className="px-4">
                <Link to="/home" className={`${pathname.match('/home') ? 'link-active' : ''}`}>Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="px-4">
                <Link to="/about-me" className={`${pathname.match('/about-me') ? 'link-active' : ''}`}>About-me</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="px-4">
                <Link to="/skill" className={`${pathname.match('/skill') ? 'link-active' : ''}`}>Skill</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="px-4">
                <Link to="/protfolio" className={`${pathname.match('/protfolio') ? 'link-active' : ''}`}>Protfolio</Link>
            </li>
            <li className="pl-4">
                <Link to="/contact" className={`${pathname.match('/contact') ? 'link-active' : ''}`}>Contact</Link>
            </li>
        </>
    );
}

export default NavItems;
```

--- Thanks ---

Comment: is it possible to match against 2 paths? So for example if one of the paths is true set the class to active

Something like this: ${pathname.match('/protfolio' || /anotherpath)

Comment: @LyubomirIvanovValchev you can use logical operator like as: (${pathname.match('/protfolio') || ${pathname.match("/anotherpath") )? 'active-url' : ' '

Comment: can you suggest a better way if we have more path on single tab

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Vijey has a bit of a problem when you're using *react-redux* for state management and some of the parent components are **'connected'** to the redux store. The *activeClassName* is applied to *Link* only when the page is refreshed, and is not dynamically applied as the current route changes.

This is to do with the *react-redux*'s connect function, as it suppresses context updates. To disable suppression of context updates, you can set `pure: false` when calling the `connect()` method like this:

```
//your component which has the custom NavLink as its child. 
//(this component may be the any component from the list of 
//parents and grandparents) eg., header

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { someprops: state.someprops }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null, null, {
  pure: false
})(Header);
```

Check the issue here: [reactjs#470](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/470)

Check `pure: false` documentation here: [docs](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#my-views-arent-updating-when-something-changes-outside-of-redux)

Answer (score 1):

Its very easy to do that, react-router-dom provides all.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { matchPath, withRouter } from 'react-router';
    
class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return(
       <ul className="sidebar-menu">
      <li className="header">MAIN NAVIGATION</li>
      <li className={matchPath(this.props.location.pathname, { path: "/dashboard" }) ? 'active' : ''}><Link to="dashboard"><i className="fa fa-dashboard"></i> 
        <span>Dashboard</span></Link></li>
      <li className={matchPath(this.props.location.pathname, { path: "/email_lists" }) ? 'active' : ''}><Link to="email_lists"><i className="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> 
        <span>Email Lists</span></Link></li>
      <li className={matchPath(this.props.location.pathname, { path: "/billing" }) ? 'active' : ''}><Link to="billing"><i className="fa fa-credit-card"></i> 
        <span>Buy Verifications</span></Link></li>
    </ul>
      )
   }
}
    
export default withRouter(NavBar);
```

Wrapping You Navigation Component with withRouter() HOC will provide few props to your component:
1. match
2. history
3. location

here i used matchPath() method from react-router to compare the paths and decide if the **'li'** tag should get "active" class name or not. and Im accessing the location from this.props.location.pathname.

changing the path name in props will happen when our link is clicked, and location props will get updated NavBar also get re-rendered and active style will get applied

Answer (score 1):

Since router v4 I am using 'refs' for setting the parent active class:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <NavLink
      innerRef={setParentAsActive}
      activeClassName="is-active"
      to={link}
    >
    {text}
  </NavLink>
</ul>
```

`NavLink`'s  `innerRef` prop accepts callback function, which will receive DOM node as an argument. You can use then any DOM manipulation possible, in this case simply set parent element (`<li>`) to have the same class:

```
  const setParentAsActive = node => {
    if (node) {
      node.parentNode.className = node.className;
    }
  };
```

Drawbacks:

- `<a>` will have unnecessary `is-active` class (as you only need it for `<li>`), or you can remove this class in the callback func.
- if you change the element structure, f.e. wrap `a` tag inside a `span`, your callback will stop working, but it's possible to write more sofisticated DOM traverse function
- you have to do some DOM manipulation

Answer (score 1):

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
<Container>
    <Navbar.Brand>
        <Nav.Link as="{NavLink}" to="/">Brand Name</Nav.Link>
    </Navbar.Brand>
    <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
    <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
        <nav className="me-auto">
            <Nav.Link as="{NavLink}" to="/" exact>Home</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as="{NavLink}" to="/about">About</Nav.Link>
            <Nav.Link as="{NavLink}" to="/contact">Contact</Nav.Link>
            <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
                <Nav.Link as="{NavLink}" to="/page1">Dropdown Link 1</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as="{NavLink}" to="/page2">Dropdown Link 2</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link as="{NavLink}" to="/page3">Dropdown Link 3</Nav.Link>
            </NavDropdown>
        </nav>
    </Navbar.Collapse>
</Container>
```

Comment: Some explanation would make this a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

react-router-dom@v6

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

<NavLink className = {isActive => isActive? 'active-css-class': 'general-css-class'}>link</NavLink>
```

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

class NavBar extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li><NavLink to='/1' activeClassName="active">1</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to='/2' activeClassName="active">2</NavLink></li>
          <li><NavLink to='/3' activeClassName="active">3</NavLink></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

this works for my...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Use React Hooks.**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const Table = () => {

const [activeMenu, setActiveMenu] = useState('transaction');

return(
<>
 <Link className="flex-1 mr-2">
          <a
            id="transaction"
            className={
              activeMenu == 'transaction'
                ? 'text-center block border border-blue-500 rounded py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white'
                : 'text-center block border border-white rounded hover:border-gray-200 text-blue-500 hover:bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4'
            }
            href="#"
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveMenu('transaction');
            }}>
            Recent Transactions
          </a>
        </Link>
        <Link className="flex-1 mr-2">
          <a
            id="account"
            className={
              activeMenu == 'account'
                ? 'text-center block border border-blue-500 rounded py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white'
                : 'text-center block border border-white rounded hover:border-gray-200 text-blue-500 hover:bg-gray-200 py-2 px-4'
            }
            href="#"
            onClick={() => {
              setActiveMenu('account');
            }}>
            Account Statement
          </a>
        </LInk>

</>
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```xml
<NavLink to='/' activeClassName='active'>
        Home
</NavLink>
```

I just used `NavLink` and `activeClassName` without wrapping it up in any component or something but my Code still works :)

Answer (score 0):

We can use `NavLink` tag to highlight active link using `isActive` property

**style:**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
active: {
    borderBottom: '1px solid white',
    color: 'yellow',
    fontSize: '14px',
    marginLeft: '16px',
    textDecoration: 'none',
},}));
```

**Component:**

```
const classes = useStyles()
<NavLinks {...classes}/>
const NavLinks = classes => {
    return (<>
        <NavLink 
             to='/' 
             className={
             useCallback(({isActive}) => isActive ? classes.active : classes.link)}
        >
            Home
        </NavLink>
    </>)
}
```

Comment: May be a stupid question, but why using `useCallback` here ?

Answer (score 0):

In - react material-ui, react-router-dom V5

```
<NavLink style={(isActive)=>({textDecoration: 'none', color: isActive ? '#1976d2':'inherit'})} to={`/`}>{`text`}</NavLink>
```

this way can apply the active link style

Answer (score 0):

instead of Link, import NavLink from react-router-dom and use NavLink property (activeClass)

```js
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

<NavLink activeClassName="active  to="dashboard" > dashboard</NavLink>
```

And Apply css to the active class :

```css
.active {
  color: #b53a20 !important;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

In react-router-dom documantion you use navlink instead of link.
https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

```
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom"; 
<Nav>
  <NavLink exact activeClassName="active--link" to="/" className="your class" > Home </NavLink> 
 <NavLink exact to="/classes" activeClassName="active--link" className="your class" > Classes </NavLink>
</Nav>
<NavLink to="/hello" activeClassName="active">Hello</NavLink>
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30305013)

Comment: import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";
<Nav>
                <NavLink
                  exact
                  activeClassName="active--link"
                  to="/"
                  className="your class"
                >
                  Home
                </NavLink>
                <NavLink
                  exact
                  to="/classes"
                  activeClassName="active--link"
                  className="your class"
                >
                  Classes
                </NavLink>
</Nav>

Comment: @AbhishekDutt i hope this will help..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70359939/9166529

Answer (score -7):

Using Jquery for active link:

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav a').filter(function() {
        return this.href==location.href
    })
    .parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')

    $('#nav a').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active')
    })
});
```

Use Component life cycle method or document ready function as specified in Jquery.

Comment: Dude, it is wrong to answer to the question in React with JQuery approach