# How to highlight active link-element in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of link-elements, the clicked link-element shall have another background-color. What is the best way to achieve that in react.js ?

```
 render() {
   return (
        <div>
          <Link></Link>
          <Link></Link>
  ....
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way using React Router to set an active class on the wrapper to the Link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418254/is-there-a-way-using-react-router-to-set-an-active-class-on-the-wrapper-to-the-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should simply be able to apply the acctiveClassName attribute to the Link like so

```
<Link to="/about" activeClassName="active">About</Link>
```

see this [link](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-tutorial/tree/master/lessons/05-active-links) for more info.

Comment: Pleasure is all mine! Took me a minute to understand the reference to my username :) Thank you tho.