# React.js implement menu [highlight active link]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, toggle

The following React.js code renders a navbar with two links named 'about' and 'project'.  On page load the 'about' link is active and colored red.  When the other link is clicked the state of the navbar is set to 'project', 'about' link style is set back, and 'project' is colored red.

I achieve this by attaching a click handler to both link tags, and set the state of active to the name of the event.target.innerHTML.

I'm new to react, and I feel this is a really verbose way of going about this.  I am aware that there is an activeClassName prop you can pass to a react-router link, but I want a way that does not use it.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link, Route } from 'react-router'

export default class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            active: 'about'
        }
        this._handleClick = this._handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    _handleClick(e) {
         this.setState({
            active: e.target.innerHTML
         });
    }

    render() {
        let aboutStyle;
        let projectStyle;

        if (this.state.active === 'about') {
            aboutStyle = { color: '#ff3333' };
            projectStyle = {};
        } else {
            aboutStyle = {};
            projectStyle = { color: '#ff3333' };
        }

        return (
        <div className='navbar'> 
            <Link to='/'><h2>BK &#47;&#47;</h2></Link>
            <div className='menu'>
                <Link style={aboutStyle} onClick={this._handleClick} to='about'>about</Link>
                <Link style={projectStyle} onClick={this._handleClick} to='projects'>projects</Link>
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

maybe slightly less verbose... in Pseudocode

```
const menuItems = [
   'projects',
   'about',
];

class MenuExample extends React.Component {

  _handleClick(menuItem) { 
    this.setState({ active: menuItem });
  }

  render () { 
    const activeStyle = { color: '#ff3333' };

    return (
       <div className='menu'>  
         {menuItems.map(menuItem => 
            <Link 
             style={this.state.active === menuItem ? activeStyle : {}} 
             onClick={this._handleClick.bind(this, menuItem)}
            > 
              {menuItem}
            </Link>
         )}
       </div>
    );    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 32):

At this day you can use NavLink from `react-router-dom`. This object supports attributes as `activeClassName`, `activeStyle`, or `isActive` (for functions).

```js
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

<NavLink to='about' activeClassName="active">about</NavLink>

// Or specifing active style
<NavLink to='about' activeStyle={{color: "red"}}>about</NavLink>

// If you use deep routes and you need an exact match
<NavLink exact to='about/subpath' activeClassName="active">about</NavLink>
```

For more options read documentation: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Comment: But there is something to consider, you should add the exact keyword to each navlilnk, unless you will get multiple links highlighted at the same time.

Comment: Great and simple solution!

Comment: @Zeinab currently `exact` is for the deep routes like: `path/subpath` to separate them all `path`, `path/subpath` and etc

Comment: @Zeinab thanks to notice, changed example a bit

Answer (score 0):

Using `NavLink` in place of `Link` gives you the opportunity to set your preferred style for the active page/link.

So you can go ahead and set the style in CSS like this.

```css
.active {
  color: 'red'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `NavLink` to highlight the active by writing custom class handling based on de-structured `isActive` property

```
    <NavLink 
         to='/' 
         className={
         useCallback(({isActive}) => isActive ? classes.active : classes.link)}
    >
        Home
    </NavLink>
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72520423/4652706

Answer (score 0):

As of ***React Router v6***, `activeClassName` prop will not work. Find the solution here, [ReactJS - Unknown prop `activeClassName` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43146460/reactjs-unknown-prop-activeclassname-on-a-tag-remove-this-prop-from-the-e)