# ReactJS - Unknown prop `activeClassName` on <a> tag. Remove this prop from the element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react 15.4.2 and react-router4.0.0 and This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

Here is my Code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Route,Link} from 'react-router-dom'


 const AboutPage = () => {
 return(
    <section>
        <h2>This is About page</h2>
        <Link activeClassName="active" to="/about/nestedone">Nestedone</Link>
        {' '}
        <Link activeClassName="active" to="/about/nestedtwo">Nested two</Link>
    </section>
)
}

const HomePage = () => {
return(
    <section>
        <h2>This is Home page</h2>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
    </section>
)
}

const NestedOne = () => {
return (
    <section>
        <h2>Nested page 1</h2>
    </section>
)
}


const NestedTwo = () => {
return (
    <section>
        <h2>Nested page 2</h2>
    </section>
)
}


 ReactDOM.render(
 <Router> 
  <section>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
    <Route path="/about/nestedone" component={NestedOne} />
    <Route path="/about/nestedtwo" component={NestedTwo} />
 </section>
 </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I browse `/about`, I am getting this error:

> "Warning: Unknown prop `activeClassName` on  tag. Remove this prop from the element.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: you may want to use the `activeclassName` property instead

Comment: I don't see activeClassName at all here https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/Link.js

Maybe you should use 'react-router' instead

Comment: In about page, i am just trying to set an active link depending on my URL when I am in /about/nestedone or /about/nestedtwo.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The [`activeClassName`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeClassName-string) property is not a property of `Link` but of `NavLink`.

So, just change your code to use `NavLink` instead of `Link`:

```
const AboutPage = () => {
 return(
    <section>
        <h2>This is About page</h2>
        <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/about/nestedone">Nestedone</NavLink>
        {' '}
        <NavLink activeClassName="active" to="/about/nestedtwo">Nested two</NavLink>
    </section>
)
```

Remember to import the `NavLink` from the `react-router-dom`:

```
import {  NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
```

Comment: This fixed my issue. Weird, NavLink isn't even listed in the docs: http://knowbody.github.io/react-router-docs/api/Link.html#

Comment: I'm getting this error even with NavLink... not sure why it's being thrown.

Comment: @captDaylight may you share a fiddle?

Answer (score 41):

From **v6** onwards of react-router replace `activeClassName` with `className` and use `navData.isActive` to toggle style.

---

Old way:

```
<NavLink to="/home" activeClassName="active-style">Home</NavLink>
```

v6 onwards:

```
<NavLink to="/home" className={(navData) => (navData.isActive ? "active-style" : 'none')}>Home</NavLink>
```

or you can also destructure `isActive` from `navData`:

```
 <NavLink to="/home" className={({isActive}) => (isActive ? "active-style" : 'none')}>Home</NavLink>
```

Comment: thanks for this answer.  It worked perfectly for me.  Instead of `'none'` I used `null` to prevent a non-active class, i.e. `className={({isActive}) => (isActive ? 'active' : null)}` 

Comment: But do you even really need all that code in the className attribute?  Unlike "Link" "NavLink" seems to automatically activate whatever style is associated with the link if it's clicked on.  See this repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/router-63-navlink-freeze-t65hnb

Comment: I've noticed that you can also just add a class "active" to CSS and React will automatically apply it to active NavLink

Answer (score 12):

In React Router v6 `activeClassName` has been changed to just `className` where a prop `isActive` can be used to manipulate the styling.

For more info
https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#remove-activeclassname-and-activestyle-props-from-navlink-

```
const AboutPage = () => {
    return(
        <section>
        <h2>This is About page</h2>
        <NavLink className={({ isActive }) => isActive? "active": ''} to="/about/nestedone">Nestedone</NavLink>
        {' '}
        <NavLink className={({ isActive }) => isActive? "active": ''} to="/about/nestedtwo">Nested two</NavLink>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: The correct answer after reactjs update to V6.

Answer (score 8):

`activeClassName` is not a property of `Link` but of [`NavLink`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink).

Since react-router [v4 beta8](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/CHANGES.md#v400-beta8), the property is `active` by default. Verify which version is installed in your node modules folder

Comment: thanks, active still not working, anyways I downgrade it to 3. everything work's fine, except IndexRoute

Comment: are you importing `{NavLink} from 'react-router-dom'`?

Answer (score 4):

My issue was that I was using `reactstrap` and importing their `NavLink` element which does NOT have the attribute `activeClassName`. Make sure you import `NavLink` from the react-router library like this:

`import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'`

Answer (score 3):

Using `activeclassname` instead of `activeClassName` fixed it for me, like so:

```
<NavLink to="/home" activeclassname="active">Home</NavLink>
```