# Underline on menu item when navigate

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, gatsby

I am using gatsby on react and have a nav menu with links, would like to when clicked on the link a border bottom show when in that current page, at the moment the border only appears with hover.

```html
       <ul className="men" id="menu">
            <li className="menuSob">
              <Link className="menuItem" to="/about/">
                sobre a magnet
              </Link>
             </li>
             <li className="menuRep">
              <Link className="menuItem" to="/representacoes/">
                representacoes
              </Link>
             </li>
             <li className="menuServ">
              <Link className="menuItem" to="/servicos/">
               servicos
              </Link>
             </li>
             <li className="menuContent">
              <Link className="menuItem" to="/conteudo/">
                conteudo
              </Link>
             </li>
             <li className="menuCont">
              <Link className="menuItem" to="/contato/">
                contato
              </Link>
             </li>
       </ul>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React.js implement menu \[highlight active link\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42297728/react-js-implement-menu-highlight-active-link)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gatsby Link allows you to do that by using `activeClassName` or `activeStyle` property. Like this:

```
   <li className="menuSob">
     <Link className="menuItem" to="/about/" activeClassName={`active`}>
            sobre a magnet
     </Link>
   </li>
```

Then in your `.scss`:

```
.active{
  text-decoration: underline
}
```

You can check for further information in [Gatsby Link documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/gatsby-link/#add-custom-styles-for-the-currently-active-link). Gatsby, in fact, extends from React routing so, you have all their benefits plus some other features provided by Gatsby. For instance, you can set a     `partiallyActive={true}` property in each `<Link>` which will match and set as "active" all paths under the route path. For example:

```
      <Link className="menuItem" to="/contato/" activeClassName={`active`} partiallyActive={true}>
        contato
      </Link>
```

Will set as "active" all paths under `/contacto` (i.e: `/contacto/give-me-five`, `/contacto/etc`, and so on).

Comment: thank you very much, I'm new on gatsby and did not know of this