# How can i change className to active on li on exact route in reactJS

Tags: reactjs

> How can we change parent li className to active on the clicked route,
>   any help would be appreciated

Problem is that li is the parent of ROUTER->LINK

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Link,
  Route,
  Switch,
} from 'react-router-dom';

class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <header className="nk-header nk-header-opaque">
                <nav className="nk-navbar nk-navbar-top nk-navbar-sticky nk-navbar-transparent nk-navbar-autohide">
                    <div className="container">
                        <div className="nk-nav-table">

                            <a href="index.html" className="nk-nav-logo">
                                <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" width="90" />
                            </a>


                            <ul className="nk-nav nk-nav-right hidden-md-down" data-nav-mobile="#nk-nav-mobile">
                                <li className="active">
                                     <Link to="/" activeClassName="active">Home</Link>
                                </li>
                                <li className="  ">
                                     <Link to="/Product" activeClassName="active">Product</Link>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>     
        );
    }
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: @ Raj please refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418254/how-do-i-add-an-active-class-to-a-link-from-react-router

Comment: change <Link to <NavLink https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink which is a special version of the <Link> that will add styling attributes to the rendered element when it matches the current URL.

Comment: @maxli thanks for reply, but i have to add class on li not to link

Comment: create a function const activeClass = (route) => { return if (this.props.location.pathname === route) "active" : null } use on <li className={activeClass("product")}>

Comment: @max thanks its working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Add this in render

```
const activeClass = (route) => { return location.pathname === route ? "active" : null }
```

> And li should be this:

```
 <li className={activeClass("/")}>
      <Link to="/">Home</Link>
 </li>
 <li className={activeClass("/Product")}>
      <Link to="/Product">Product</Link>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 3):

First thing its better to construct a JSON obj of a menu item,

```
  const modules : [
  {
    id : 1,
    name : 'Home',
    linkTo : '/',
  },
  {
    id : 2,
    name : 'Product',
    linkTo : '/product',
  }
]
```

Now in your render method get the requested path name

```
let requestedPath = this.context.router.route.location.pathname;
```

Now, render the menu items

```
return(
        <header className="nk-header nk-header-opaque">
            <nav className="nk-navbar nk-navbar-top nk-navbar-sticky nk-navbar-transparent nk-navbar-autohide">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="nk-nav-table">
                        <a href="index.html" className="nk-nav-logo">
                            <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="" width="90" />
                        </a>
                        <ul className="nk-nav nk-nav-right hidden-md-down" data-nav-mobile="#nk-nav-mobile">
                          {modules.map((module, index) => {
                            let className = module.linkTo === requestedPath ? 'active' : '';
                            return (
                              <li className="active" key={index}>
                                   <Link to={module.linkTo} className={className}>{module.name}</Link>
                              </li>
                            )
                          })}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    );
```

> Note : I didnt compiled the code.