# Cannot give class to current link in react

Tags: reactjs

I have some links in a nav menu that outputs html something like this:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/subs">Subs</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to add a class only to the current page link in the nav menu (e.g. if you're on the / page then the home link should have a class added to it) as per the solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34418254/how-do-i-add-an-active-class-to-a-link-from-react-router) post, however, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined
```

Here is the component:

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {navLinks} from "../util/nav-links";

export default class NavMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var isActive = this.context.router.route.location.pathname === this.props.to;
    var className = isActive ? 'active' : '';

    const lis = navLinks.map(link => (
      <li>
        <Link className={className} to={link.href} key={link.href}>{link.name}</Link>
      </li>
      )
    )

    return (
      <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
          {lis}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

And the /util/nav-links.js file:

```
export const navLinks = [
  {
    name: "home",
    href: "/"
  },
  {
    name: "subs",
    href: "/subs"
  }
];
```

Why is this error occuring? If the two variables `isActive` and `className` and the `className` in the link tag are removed then the code works. Also, if there's a better way of achieving this then does anyone have any other methods?

Thanks for any help here. Stackblitz demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jhedf8?file=src%2Fcomponents%2Fnav-menu.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 Options from the link you provided that should work for you:

Option 1 (Answer by Matt):

React-Router V4 comes with a [NavLink](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink) component out of the box
To use, simply set the activeClassName attribute to the class you have appropriately styled, or directly set activeStyle to the styles you want. See the [docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md) for more details.

`<NavLink to="/hello" activeClassName="active" >Hello</NavLink>`

Option 2 (Answer by ghostkravis):

```js
export default class Navbar extends React.Component {
render(){
const { location } = this.props;

const homeClass = location.pathname === "/" ? "active" : "";
const aboutClass = location.pathname.match(/^\/about/) ? "active" : "";
const contactClass = location.pathname.match(/^\/contact/) ? "active" : "";


return (
<div>
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li className={homeClass}><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li className={aboutClass}><Link to="about" activeClassName="active">About</Link></li>
        <li className={contactClass}><Link to="contact" activeClassName="active">Contact</Link></li>
      </ul>

</div>
    );}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could modify your code to accept [NavLink](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/NavLink.md) instead of `Link` and you can remove all the code related in generating active class that you have inside render method..

Changes as follows:

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
```

**to:**

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Then,

```
<Link className={className} to={link.href} key={link.href}>{link.name}</Link>
```

**to:**

```
<NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to={link.href} key={link.href}>{link.name}</NavLink>
```

**nav_menu.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import {navLinks} from "../util/nav-links";

export default class NavMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const lis = navLinks.map(link => (
      <li>
        <NavLink exact activeClassName="active" to={link.href} key={link.href}>{link.name}</NavLink>
      </li>
      )
    )

    return (
      <div id="navbar">
        <ul>
          {lis}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**style.css:**

```
.
.
.

.active {
   color: #13aa52 !important;
}
```

**Forked Stackblitz:**

> **https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sxukcd**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `Link` component, use `NavLink` component from `react-router-dom`. `NavLink` component takes a prop named `activeClassName` whose value is the class that will be used for the styling to indicate which nav link is active.

```
<NavLink activeClassName="active" to={link.href} exact>{link.name}</NavLink>
```

Don't forget to define the class in CSS which you use as a value for `activeClassName` prop.

For details, see: [React Router - NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink)

---

Not related to the issue but inside the `.map()` method in `NavMenu` component, you have added `key` prop on the `Link` component but it should be added on the outer `li` element.

```
const lis = navLinks.map(link => (
  <li key={link.name}>
    <NavLink activeClassName="active" to={link.href} exact>
      {link.name}
    </NavLink>
  </li>
));
```

Also note that using `NavLink` component will remove the need of following two statements in `NavMenu` component

```
var isActive = this.context.router.route.location.pathname === this.props.to;
var className = isActive ? 'active' : '';
```

Answer (score 1):

For me what worked has is using NavLink as it has this active class property.

1. First import it

   ```
   import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
   ```
2. Use an activeClassName to get the active class property.

   ```
   <NavLink to="/" activeClassName="active">
     Home
   </NavLink>

   <NavLink to="/store" activeClassName="active">
    Store
   </NavLink>

   <NavLink to="/about" activeClassName="active">
    About Us
   </NavLink>
   ```
3. Style your class in the css by the property active.

   ```
   .active{
      color:#fcfcfc;
    }
   ```